# JavaFX select item in org.controlsfx.control.GridView.GridView

Tags: gridview, javafx-2

How do I select item like ListView to handler clickListener? is there gridView sample?love u

```
        ObservableList<Image> images = FXCollections.<Image>observableArrayList(list); 

        GridView<Image> gridView = new GridView<Image>(images);
        gridView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                //TODO                  
            }               
        });

        gridView.setCellFactory(new Callback<GridView<Image>, GridCell<Image>>() {

            @Override
            public GridCell<Image> call(GridView<Image> param) {

                return new ImageGridCell() ;
            }

         });
```

How do I select item like ListView to handler clickListener?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like this as a simple way.

```
class ImageCell extends GridCell<String>{
    ImageCell(){
      setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (((MouseEvent) event).getClickCount() >= 2) {
                  //do something when it's clicked

            }

         }
      }); 
    }
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            // you can set content of cell here just as you do in 
            //javaFX apllcation 
            // and call setGraphic(root) eventually.
            // you can also call setOnAction on sub node in root rather 
            // than do it in constructor.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show me a detailed code examples how to add listener? thank you so much.

Comment: I have edited it, can you understand how to deal with your problem?